# Howto print (JavaPos Printer) with Java Jar App on Linux (Xubuntu 16.04 ) without sudo

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, sudo, javapos

I am trying to figure out a way how to start my jar app within Xubuntu without having to open a terminal and typing sudo java -jar

In case I don't do it through the terminal, my app will start but **won't connect to** the JavaPos Thermal Printer; as a result, I cannot print.

Hope someone among you could assist me in this matter.

Comment: This is better asked on http://askubuntu.com. There is probably a problem with your cups setup, so that the account does not have privileges to the printer

Comment: Tony thanks for your input. I will start a question there.